# Can I create a second vector which contains the identical objects as the first vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to convert a performance critical part of a Java code to a C++ code.

In Java I work with lists containing a small sample of the original list. When I add objects of the first list to the second list actually only a reference to the object is stored, so I do not copy the object. This is what I would like to achieve in C++ also. Unfortunately I have not found a way to do so as the push_back method seems to create a deep copy instead.

Java code:

```
class Data {

    Data(int id){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = "Name " + id;
    }
    public int id;
    public String name = "";
    public boolean isFancy = false;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Data data = new Data(i);
            dataList.add(data);
        }

        List<Data> dataSublist = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSublist.add(dataList.get(2));
        dataSublist.add(dataList.get(3));
        dataSublist.add(dataList.get(8));
        dataSublist.forEach(data -> data.isFancy = true); // change isFancy in subList to alter the original object

        System.out.println("Data 3 original isFancy = " + dataList.get(3).isFancy); // is true

    }
}
```

C++ code:

```
class Data {
public:
    Data(int id) { id_ = id; };

    int id_ = 0;
    std::string name_ = "";
    bool isFancy_ = false;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> dataList;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Data data = Data(i);
        dataList.push_back(data);
    }

    std::vector<Data> dataSublist;
    dataSublist.push_back(dataList[2]);
    dataSublist.push_back(dataList[3]);
    dataSublist.push_back(dataList[8]);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSublist.size(); i++) {
        dataSublist[i].isFancy_ = true; // change isFancy in subList to alter the original object
    }

    std::cout << "Data 3 original isFancy = " << ((dataList[3].isFancy_) ? "true" : "false"); // is false

}
```

How to I get the output to "true" here?

Comment: You get it by realizing that C++ is not Java, and objects in C++ work in fundamentally different ways. The C++ equivalent of the Java `Data` object instance is not an instance of `Data`, but an instance of `std::shared_ptr<Data>`. Did you try changing both of your vectors to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Data>>`? Do you know what `std::shared_ptr` is, how it works, and how to use it?

Comment: I dont think anybody wants to discourage you to ask quesitons in general. I'd like to encourage you to do some research on the difference between C++ and Java, on how Java is about references and how C++ is about values, because thats what this question lacks, a bit of research

Comment: Unless you really need `std::shared_ptr`’s thread-safe reference counting and the atomic instructions overhead associated with it, you may want to consider a different solution, e.g. a long-lived vector of the actual objects as a backing store and vectors of pointers into that vector (populated e.g. using `std::transform` or the like) as short(er)-lived “copies”. Alternatively, a vector of `std::unique_ptr`s could be the long-lived backing store if polymorphism needs to be used or if the objects are big. That would also avoid `std::shared_ptr`’s awesome yet expensive atomic reference counting.

Comment: How to translate code: 1) Fully understand the observable behaviour of the source code. 2) Write a new program in the new language that reproduces the observable behaviour of the original code taking advantage of the new language's idioms and following its best practices. 3) Exhaustively test the old and new programs against each other to ensure identical observable behaviour. TL;DR version: Code doesn't matter. Only behaviour matters. The code simply describes the behaviour.

Comment: I did not downvote this question. Please refrain from making unwarranted assumptions.

Comment: *as the push_back method seems to create a deep copy instead.* -- The issue that others are probably having is that you say "seems to create a deep copy".  Of course it makes a deep copy -- that's how C++ works.  You should have been well aware of that before embarking on converting the Java code to C++.  It gives the impression you entered C++ unprepared, and to get started, translated Java to C++ using line-by-line analysis of both languages (which almost always never works for anything but toy programs).

Comment: Sam, sorry for taken that assumption.

Comment: I am not sure what the expectations are here. Of course I am just getting into the language concept and when I say "seems to create a deep copy" then with respect of the issues with deep copy and nested objects, which I indeed did not research the specific handling in C++. However, I got some interesting and helpful insights from your comments. I naively was hoping for some build in pointer arithmetic functionality for vector as C++ is coming from C. I could not find anything in the reference or tutorials. Forgive me for not reading the full C++ documentation beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The learning curve for C++ is not the best. I don't think it's a good idea to just jump into it and try to write efficient code without any experience. Anyway, here it is, I hope it helps:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Data
{

public:
    Data(int id)
        : id_{id}
    {
    }

    int id_;
    std::string name_ = "";
    bool isFancy_ = false;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Data>> dataList{};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Data> data = std::make_shared<Data>(i); // Equivalent to `new Data(i)` in Java.
        dataList.push_back(data);
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Data>> dataSublist{};

    dataSublist.push_back(dataList[2]);
    dataSublist.push_back(dataList[3]);
    dataSublist.push_back(dataList[8]);

    for (auto data : dataSublist)
    {
        // The `->` represents an indirection and has nothig to do with lambdas.
        data->isFancy_ = true;
    }

    std::cout << "Data 3 original isFancy = " << std::boolalpha << dataList[3]->isFancy_ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this code here. Looking at the comment of Andrej with the atomic and management overhead I might be going for a different concept.

Comment: Side note: `std::shared_pointer`s only cause overhead when you copy and destroy them, not when you dereference them (or pass them by reference, which is often frowned upon, but IMO has its benefits). So they may well be a good solution in case you want to reference some objects from multiple different vectors / sets / whatevers _and_ make sure each object’s lifetime is maintained correctly + _individually_. OTOH, if you always copy the entire vector, without changing its order / size, then although `std::shared_pointer`s will work fine, they won’t be the best solution…

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be lacking is an understanding that in Java, objects are *reference types*, but in C++ they are *value types* instead.

Your Java code is acting on *references* to objects.  Your C++ code fails because your 2nd `vector` contains *copies* of the objects in the 1st `vector`, rather than *references* to the objects.  Your loop is modifying the copies, not the originals.

You can do the same logic in C++ as in Java by using pointers, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

class Data {
public:
    Data(int id) : id(id), name("Name " + std::to_string(id)) { }

    int id;
    std::string name;
    bool isFancy = false;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> dataList;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // dataList.push_back(Data(i));
        dataList.emplace_back(i);
    }

    std::vector<Data*> dataSublist;
    dataSublist.push_back(&dataList[2]); // note the '&' here!
    dataSublist.push_back(&dataList[3]);
    dataSublist.push_back(&dataList[8]);

    /*
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataSublist.size(); ++i) {
        dataSublist[i]->isFancy = true; // change isFancy in subList to alter the original object
    }
    */
    for (Data *data : dataSublist) {
        data->isFancy = true; // change isFancy in subList to alter the original object
    }

    std::cout << "Data 3 original isFancy = " << std::boolalpha << dataList[3].isFancy; // is true
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/RJSJb0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try the same approach before I asked the question. That did not work out because the original vector moved and the pointers pointed to garbage. So, what was different? I did create both lists within a class (pointers are fine) and then assigned (=) the whole class to another variable, effectively creating a deep copy of the original class to a new memory location. All I needed to change was make that class variable a pointer and assign with new.
It is not, that I am not aware that C++ is 'by value', the question was how to circumvent that. Lesson learned.

Comment: The alternative is to overload `operator=` in the class to not copy the 2nd vector of pointers, but to reset it to point them at the newly copied objects in the 1st vector. Otherwise, make the 1st vector store `make_shared` pointers, then copying both vectors as-is is ok.